# Windows Phone Dashboard Showing No Downloads

Tags: windows-phone, dashboard, appstats

I have recently (only two days ago) published an app in Windows Phone Store and want to track the download counts. When I enter Windows Phone Dashboard I can see reviews, but in the quick stats it says that "There haven't been any app downloads in the last 30 days.". I can also see logins in the dashboard of the API that I am using so there must be some downloads. Does it take some time (if so how long) for downloads to be seen in the reports or is there some kind of a glinch (which I doubt) in the dashboard?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Be patient, it normally takes more than 2 days.

Comment: @JustinXL thanks for your comment. May you write this as an answer with your experiences of first days in the store so that I can mark it as an answer. Strangely I was unable to find the refresh interval of the dashboard anywhere.